# Is there any ways to tune JSDoc with markdown plugin gfm to highlight github markdown syntax right?

Tags: github, syntax-highlighting, markdown, jsdoc

Is there any ways to tune **JSDoc** with *markdown* plugin **gfm** to highlight github makrdown syntax?

## Example

For example here is original highlighting:

https://github.com/darlingjs/darlingjs

[image]

and gfm (without highlighting) result:

http://darlingjs.github.io/docs/index.html

[image]

and by the way jsdoc has *prettyprint*.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add syntax highlight to my markdown tutorials using prettyprint. It's not GFM, but it's better than nothing :)

I just changed the code sections from:

````
``` javascript
// ...
// js code
// ...
```
````

to:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
// ...
// js code
// ...
</pre>
```